# How to install DEAP with Conda without write permissions

Tags: python, pip, conda, deap

I'm trying to use the [DEAP](https://github.com/DEAP/deap) evolutionary algorithm package at University. I don't have privileges to use pip, so I have to use Conda. When I try `conda install deap` in the Anaconda prompt I get a `PackageNotFoundError`. Any idea how I can get it?

Comment: You don't need root privileges to use pip, use the --user switch to install into your home. But that error might stay.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge deap
```

as suggested on the [Anaconda Website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/deap)?

Comment: Tried that, didn't have write permissions. Using virtual envs worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a virtual environment to get it to work.

```
conda create -n myProject

source activate myProject

conda install -c conda-forge deap
```